# No elements found when parsing eBay's api result xml

Tags: c#, xml, ebay-api

I'm trying to search eBay via C# and XML. I can see that I'm getting a valid XML response, by writing out the XML to a string, but cannot parse it using C# - I just keep getting told that there are no elements.

Here's my code, with my appname key removed:

```
   string xmldata = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
    xmldata += "<findItemsAdvancedRequest xmlns='http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services'>";
    xmldata += "<keywords>sneakers</keywords>";
    xmldata += "<categoryId>1</categoryId>";
    xmldata += "<descriptionSearch>false</descriptionSearch>";
    xmldata += "<paginationInput>";
    xmldata += "<entriesPerPage>5</entriesPerPage>";
    xmldata += "</paginationInput>";
    xmldata += "</findItemsAdvancedRequest>";

    string url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    //Create a HttpWebRequest object
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    //Convert xml string to a byte array      
    byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmldata);

    //Set the Method property
    req.Method = "POST";
    //Set the ContentType property of the "HttpWebRequest"
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "FindingService");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsAdvanced");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.4.0");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-GB");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "XML");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: **********************");


    //Set the ContentLength property of the "HttpWebRequest"
    req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    XDocument myXML = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = myXML.Root.Element("searchResult").Elements("item");
```

I've tried various combinations of the last line - getting the Count of the Descendants for example, but always get variations of 'no matching elements' messages. I know that the results are there: when I set a breakpoint and look at the myXML variable in Visual Studio, the XML all seems to be in the Root.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the XML you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the returned XML uses XML namespaces, while your query doesn't. Assuming the namespace is the same as the one in the XML you are sending to the server, this would work:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";

var elements = myXML.Root.Element(ns + "searchResult").Elements(ns + "item");
```

Comment: Thanks svick, that worked - I'll have to do some research though as I don't fully understand why you need to have the namespace at the start. Especially since adding those two strings looks like you'd get http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/servicesSearchresults and http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/servicesitem, but thanks!!

Comment: @Mark, you're not adding strings. `ns` is [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) and if you add a string to that, [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) is created.